# How can I check the query selected nothing?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I use Laravel framework.

Here is my query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])->get();
```

I need to check is there any result or not? In other word I need to check has any row selected or not? How can I check it?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php or equivalent

Answer (score 3):

You can use `count()`:

```
if (count($users)) {
    ....
} else {
    // No users were selected.
}
```

Comment: Thank you, upvote. Just for my information, can't I do that by using `is_null()` ?

Comment: If you're using `first()` instead of `get()` which retrieves an object instead of a collection then you should use `is_null()`